# Windows Forms touch down event

Tags: c#, winforms, touch

I'm creating a Windows Forms application that has a couple of clickable panels that require the touchscreen equivalent of the mouse down and up event.

When I'm testing with my keyboard and mouse the event are fired correctly and the application reacts as expected. However when testing on a touchscreen it is not. The only event that does work correctly is the click event but my application requires a mouse down event to continuously update a value.

Has anyone encountered a problem like this and found a solution?

Comment: Your UI just isn't very compatible with touch input.  Move your finger a bit to generate the MouseDown event.

Answer (score 3):

You have to override the WndProc, capture the messages and launch your MouseDown and MouseUp events manually

```
public const int WM_POINTERDOWN = 0x246;
public const int WM_POINTERUP = 0x247;

[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(m);
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_POINTERDOWN:
            {
                MouseEventArgs args = new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 1, this.MousePosition.X, this.MousePosition.Y, 0);
                MouseDown(this, args);                    
                break;
            }

        case WM_POINTERUP:
            {
                MouseEventArgs args = new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 1, this.MousePosition.X, this.MousePosition.Y, 0);
                MouseUp(this, args);
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best minimalistic approach I have found so far.  The MousePosition is incorrect and gives last mouse position instead of current gesture position.  Jorge Oliveira's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940143/recognize-touch-as-mousedown-event  provides the correct mouse position.

Answer (score 2):

Just doing a little reading, I think you need to override the WndProc and look for WM_TOUCH events.

Have a look at the [Windows 7 Multitouch .NET Interop Sample Library](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsTouch/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2127) which has examples on handling touch and gestures in winforms.

Comment: The link you provided does not seem to work any more? Where can I find more information about what you suggested? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure about this but, have you tried using a tap event to capture the touch, rather than the click event?