# Recognize touch as MouseDown event

Tags: c#, winforms, touch

I am building a puzzle game in C#, winforms for a touch screen.

I am able to handle touch events on mouse handlers, in fact, i did nothing at all, but it already recognizes my touches. However, there is an issue that i can't figure it out. The mouse_down, only happens when i move a bit my finger, and did not recognize the instant when i touch the screen.

Does anyone has already faced this problem?
Should i implement some touch events recognition? If so, could you please point me some documentation or examples?

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using winforms for this? WPF, and especially windows metro, have much more advanced touch support.

Comment: I know Bradley, but this have to be done in winforms. I know that wpf would be better and winforms is not the best way for games or interactions such the ones i am implementing. However this is part of a bigger project, and i have to do it like so :)

Comment: I hope you get an answer then. If I had to guess, Microsoft never intended WinForms to be used in a touch environment, so it is unlikely they have good support for it.

Comment: ... convice the project leader to switch to WPF or WinRT.

Comment: Maybe it is waiting for a 2nd finger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One suggestion that sounds as a plausible solution is to override WndProc and search for a WM_TOUCH event. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15785333/3330348

Answer (score 13):

Thanks @PiotrWolkowski

You were correct about the way i should follow...
Some other issues appear, but i solved the initial problem overriding the WndProc as showed in the following:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case Win32.WM_POINTERDOWN:
            case Win32.WM_POINTERUP:
            case Win32.WM_POINTERUPDATE:
            case Win32.WM_POINTERCAPTURECHANGED:
                break;

            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                return;
        }
        int pointerID = Win32.GET_POINTER_ID(m.WParam);
        Win32.POINTER_INFO pi = new Win32.POINTER_INFO();
        if (!Win32.GetPointerInfo(pointerID, ref pi))
        {
            Win32.CheckLastError();
        }
        Point pt = PointToClient(pi.PtPixelLocation.ToPoint());
        MouseEventArgs me = new MouseEventArgs(System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left, 1, pt.X, pt.Y, 0);
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case Win32.WM_POINTERDOWN:
                    Console.WriteLine("TOCOU" + pt);
                    (Parent as Jogo).Form1_MouseDown((this as object), me);
                break;

            case Win32.WM_POINTERUP:
                    Console.WriteLine("LEVANTOU");
                    (Parent as Jogo).Form1_MouseUp((this as object), me);
                break;

            case Win32.WM_POINTERUPDATE:
                    //Console.WriteLine("UPDATE");
                    (Parent as Jogo).Form1_MouseMove((this as object), me);
                break;
        }
    }
```

It was supported by an "Win32.cs" that can be downloaded here:

https://gist.github.com/RSchwoerer/bc5c04899c0510aefca24f088a79cebf

Hope this is helpful for you;)

Answer (score 2):

To perform touch operations correct you should not use the mouse handler event's just because touch and use the mouse handler it is going through a library built to handle touch as mouse and not what you should be using for a game your able to register your application to handle touch events using the methods from `user32.dll`, below is an example of how to implement touch handling in your application.

```
    [DllImport("user32.DLL")]
    public static extern bool RegisterTouchWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int ulFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.DLL")]
    public static extern bool UnregisterTouchWindow(IntPtr hwnd);


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RegisterTouchWindow(button1.Handle, 0);
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        UnregisterTouchWindow(button1.Handle);
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your answer adding some explanations. Avoid code only answer, take a look to : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

This can be a problem with your touch screen's driver. Many touch screen drivers have utilities that set how a touch is interpretted and sent to windows. Sometimes just updating the driver will work.