# C# Winform. How do I convert mousedown to touch and hold?

Tags: c#, winforms, touch

One of the functions in one of my old Winform programs is used as a camera control for PTZ in a conference room. Right now the program is utilized by mouse. I have been told to ditch the mouse and go touch screen.

So far I have found posts referring to gestures [MSDN Gestures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd353241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which does not seem to apply. Another post seems to be trying the same thing [Recognize touch as MouseDown event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940143/recognize-touch-as-mousedown-event). Unfortunately I am having some trouble understanding.

I have found that the default windows touch behavior to press and hold without having windows trigger a right click request is to move your finger slightly. I have found that this works, but I have to assume that people using this control would not know how to do that.

I have also read that WPF is much better for touch handling but the deadline is only a couple of weeks. I can't recreate the entire application and learn WPF in that time span.

The function is on mouse down the command to move is issues. When the mouse is released the command to stop is issued.

```
private void pRight_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
            writeDevice("cammove right\r\n");          
    }
private void pRight_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
            writeDevice("cammove stop\r\n");          
    }
```

I have tried basically adding everything from the [touch as mousedown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940143/recognize-touch-as-mousedown-event) post.

The goal is to make this behave like a mobile device. I need to have Windows not attempt to submit a right click event to the program or capture the right click and re-send as mouse down. Disabling it system wide is an option.

Im stuck. any suggestions?