# MouseDown not triggered in tablet mode

Tags: windows, winforms, windows-10, tablet

If my users (who are handicapped children) press their finger on an icon in my application, something should happen right away.

To do that, I react to the MouseDown event.

What I expect is the following:

1. User touches screen with finger: MouseDown
2. User releases finger from screen: MouseClick, MouseUp

However, in Windows 10 with Tablet Mode activated, this does not work.

Instead, the sequence "MouseDown", "MouseClick", "MouseUp" is triggered only when the finger is lifted.

How could I make it so that I get a notification about the finger touch?

Sample code in VB.NET:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
        Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("mousedown")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
        Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("mouseup")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
        Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("mouseclick")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6fb79399-2349-4c36-bbea-8ae5660801f9/mousedown-doesnt-fire-until-finger-is-removed-from-the-touch-surface?forum=winforms

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940143/recognize-touch-as-mousedown-event