# Detect initial touch in a touch screen

Tags: vb.net, touch-event

I've made an application in windows forms in VB.net and I would like to detect when a touch initiates. All I get is an event when the users push up the finger, but I should need to know when the user push down the finger.

I've read some about WPF, that maybe would solve my problem (I don't know) but my program is in windows form and would take lot of hours for me to learn WPF and re-create what I have actually.

Thank you very much in advance!

I've tried all VB events and all of them raises when finishing the action, not when initiating, that is what I need.

Comment: Form.click happens when the finger is up, but Form.MouseDown should detect initial contact. Are you sure you tried that one?

Comment: Thanks tgolisch for your answer. Yes, I've tried this one and other twenty events available in VB that should be related with that... But none of them raises on clicking!

Comment: This might have already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940143/recognize-touch-as-mousedown-event